# Single Value From Drop down list shows other fields

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

Currently have an c# asp.net web aspx page with two drop down lists. The first drop down list is visible and the other is set to false on page load. My problem today is I need users to select one unique (attempt below) value from the drop down list and for that value to make the other drop down list visible.

My attempt: 
 Here is what the mark up looks like

```html
ddlCollision is the visible drop down list.

<div class="row500">
            <span class="cell200">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCollision" runat="server" Height="28px" Width="354px" Style="font-size: 18px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCollision_SelectedIndexChanged">
<asp:ListItem Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="1">People</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="2">Cars(select below)</asp:ListItem>
       
 ddlfixedobject is the non visible drop down list                 
   <div class="row500"  id="fixedObject" runat="server">
    <span class="cell200">
      <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFixedObject" runat="server" Height="28px" Width="354px" Style="font-size: 18px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlFixedObject_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Sign post</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Guardrail</asp:ListItem>
   </asp:DropDownList>     
</span>    
</div>
```

When value "2" for cars is selected i need the ddl fixed object to appear!

Here is what i have for code so far behind the indexed changed...

```
 protected void ddlCollision_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   {
        if (ddlCollision.SelectedValue == "2")

            fixedObject.Visible = true;
        else
            fixedObject.Visible = false;

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try is code in page_load event inside If(!ispostback) loop

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to post back when you update the first dropdown you may have to add AutoPostBack="True" to the first DropDownList control.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(!ispostBack)
 {
    if (ddlCollision.SelectedValue == "2")

        fixedObject.Visible = true;
    else
        fixedObject.Visible = false;

 }
```

Try this piece of code inside page_load